# Constructor logic of this.fullName = fullName & split() method

Tags: javascript, constructor, get, set

Can someone explain me:

We have a two similar codes. They functionality are the same. But in the first code we have a normal result and in the next one - very strange.

I do not understand why the results diffent, because we changing only the varient of values spliting - **from declaration in var split** **variable** in first case to **direct changing in the current this.fullName prop** in the next one. And using they in the corresponding codes below.

```
this.fullName = fullName;
var split = this.fullName.split(' ');
```

change on

```
this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');
```

We have a so different results.

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName;
  var split = this.fullName.split(' ');

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.firstName = split[0];
    },

    set: function(newFisrtName) {
        this.fullName = newFisrtName + ' ' + split[1];
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.lastName = split[1];
    },

    set: function(newLastName) {
        this.fullName = split[0] + ' ' + newLastName;
    }   
  });

}

var jone = new User("Jone Coven");

delete jone.lastName; 

jone.lastName = 'Mashow';

console.log(jone.fullName); // Jone Mashow
console.log(jone.firstName); // Jone
console.log(jone.lastName); // Coven
```

------- The second varient of the code above --------

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');


  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.firstName = this.fullName[0];
    },

    set: function(newFisrtName) {
        this.fullName = newFisrtName + ' ' + this.fullName[1];
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.lastName = this.fullName[1];
    },

    set: function(newLastName) {
        this.fullName = this.fullName[0] + ' ' + newLastName;
    }   
  });

}

var jone = new User("Jone Coven");

delete jone.lastName; 

jone.lastName = 'Mashow';

console.log(jone.fullName); // Jone Mashow
console.log(jone.firstName); // J
console.log(jone.lastName); // empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');


  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', { 
    get: function() {
        return this.firstName = this.fullName[0];
    },

    set: function(newFisrtName) { 
        this.fullName[0] = newFisrtName;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.fullName[1];
    },

    set: function(newLastName) { 
        
 this.fullName[1] = newLastName;
    }   
  });

}

var jone = new User("Jone Coven");

delete jone.lastName; 

jone.lastName = 'Mashow';

console.log(jone.fullName); 
console.log(jone.firstName); 
console.log(jone.lastName);
```

Actually, at the last name setter, you accidently have made the array to string. That is why it is behaving like so. Please see above modified code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the second declaration is in this method

```
 set: function(newLastName) {
    this.fullName = this.fullName[0] + ' ' + newLastName; // here is the problem
}
```

if you look at this line you'll see that you convert **this.fullName** from array to string

so if you try this

```
this.fullName[0] // you get J 
this.fullName[1] // you get O
```

because **this.fullName** now is a string not an array and that's why the first declaration works because you use another variable **split** and you don't change it and remains array .

so modify your code to work better